# Sorting Array by two properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to use `.sort()` to sort golf groups by their starting hole. I need the groups to be listed in the following order. 1A, 1B, 2A, 2B so on and so forth.

Currently, this is how I am sorting the data:

```js
                        <% groups = groups.sort((a, b) => (a.position > b.position && a.letter > b.letter) ? 1 : -1)%>
```

*Please ignore the abnormal HTML tags, this is being implemented in an e.js template*

Currently,the groups are displaying like this:
[image: Preview]

This is far from the order I need and if anybody has any input as to how to help with this it would be greatly appreciated!

Note:

The "position" property is the number (the 1 in the 1A)
The "letter" property is the letter (the A in the 1A)

The array in question (as logged in console)
[image: Array]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to perform the comparisons separately - first compare the numbers and return appropriately if they're different. Otherwise, if the numbers are the same, return the difference between the members with `.localeCompare`, which checks whether a character comes before another or not.

```js
const groups = [
  { position: 1, letter: 'B' },
  { position: 2, letter: 'B' },
  { position: 1, letter: 'A' },
  { position: 2, letter: 'B' },
  { position: 2, letter: 'A' },
  { position: 1, letter: 'B' },
];
groups.sort((a, b) =>
  (a.position - b.position) ||
  a.letter.localeCompare(b.letter)
);
console.log(groups.map(group => group.position + group.letter));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is you sort the array 2 times.
1st time sort by position => get array sorted_position
Second time sorting by letter from array sorted_position

Ex:

```js
 let data = [
        {position: 22, letter : "B"},
        {position: 222, letter : "A"},
        {position: 24, letter : "A"},
        {position: 2, letter : "A"},
        {position: 2, letter : "B"},
        {position: 1, letter : "B"},
        {position: 1, letter : "A"},
        {position: 4, letter : "B"},
        {position: 3, letter : "B"},
        {position: 3, letter : "A"},
        {position: 5, letter : "A"},
        {position: 5, letter : "B"},
    ]
    let sorted_position = data.sort(function(item1, item2) {
        if (item1.position < item2.position) {
            return -1
        }
        return 1;
    });
    let sorted_final = sorted_position.sort(function (item1, item2) {
        if (item1.position === item2.position) {
            if (item1.letter < item2.letter)
            return -1;
        }
        return 1
    });
    console.log("sorted_final: ", sorted_final)
```