# Sorting object by numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to sort my array one of two ways, first by overhead Ascending and then by amount Ascending.

The following code works fine for the overhead which is text but replacing a.overhead with a.amount doesn't work correctly. It displays a 1,11,15,2,22,24,3,33,35 etc where as it should be 1,2,3,11,15,22,24 etc.

```
sortedArray = [...amendedArray].sort((a,b)=>(a.Overhead.toLowerCase() > b.Overhead.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : ((b.Overhead.toLowerCase() > a.Overhead.toLowerCase()) ? -1 : 0));
```

I believe I need to use function for numbers but I got help with the above code and I can't seem to convert it to make it work in my scenario.

```
sortedArray = [...amendedArray].sort(function(a, b){ return a.Amount - b.Amount });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you include a runnable snippet (use toolbar) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: also possibly [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use a collator that can handle comparison of both strings and numbers

```js
const collator = new Intl.Collator("en", {
  sensitivity: 'base', // ignore case and accents
  numeric: true // treat numeric strings as numbers,  "1" < "2" < "10"
});

sortedArray = [...amendedArray].sort((a, b) => {
  return collator.compare(a.Overhead, b.Overhead) || collator.compare(a.Amount, b.Amount)
})
```

You can read more about the [Intl.Collator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) and the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator/Collator)

Comment: This is a duplicate multiple times over.