# Sort array on two different values and keep flat array structure

Tags: javascript, sorting, grouping

I have this array

```
const rows = [
    {data: [{text: "A",value: 100}, {text: "B",value: 74}], group: "Elephant"},
    {data: [{text: "C",value: 63}, {text: "D",value: 1}], group: "Elephant"},
    {data: [{text: "E",value: 37}, {text: "F",value: 54}], group: "Penguin"},
    {data: [{text: "G", value: 72}, {text: "H", value: 74}], group: "Lion"},
    {data: [{text: "K", value: 76}, {text: "L", value: 38}], group: "Zebra"},
    {data: [{text: "M", value: 68}, {text: "N", value: 21}], group: "Lion"},
];
```

And these sort functions

```
const _sortFunction = (
    a,
    b,
    columnIndex,
    sortOrder
) => {
    if (a && a.data && b && b.data) {
        if (a.data[columnIndex].value === b.data[columnIndex].value) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (sortOrder === "ASC") return a.data[columnIndex].value > b.data[columnIndex].value ? -1 : 1;
            if (sortOrder === "DESC") return a.data[columnIndex].value < b.data[columnIndex].value ? -1 : 1;
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
};

const sortRowsByColumn = (rows, sortProps) => {
    if (sortProps && rows) {
        const {indexOfColumnToSort, sortOrder} = sortProps;
        const rowsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows))
        return rowsCopy.sort((a, b) => _sortFunction(a, b, indexOfColumnToSort, sortOrder));
    }
    return rows;
};
```

Which gives me `console.log(sortRowsByColumn(rows, {indexOfColumnToSort: 1, sortOrder: "ASC"}))`

```
[
{data: [{text: "A", value: 100}, {text: "B", value: 74}], group: "Elephant"}, 
{data: [{text: "G", value: 72}, {text: "H", value: 74}], group: "Lion"}, 
{data: [{text: "E", value: 37}, {text: "F", value: 54}], group: "Penguin"}, 
{data: [{ text: "K", value: 76}, {text: "L", value: 38}], group: "Zebra"}, 
{data: [{text: "M", value: 68}, {text: "N", value: 21}], group: "Lion"}, 
{data: [{text: "C", value: 63}, {text: "D", value: 1}],group: "Elephant"}
]
```

However, what I cannot get my head around is the following:
The updated `sortRowsByColumn()` function should

1. sort the `rows` array based on the `group` key (alphabetically)
2. then sort based on the column index for each group

all of this without loosing the original array structure. Basically like a grouping and sorting for each group, without modifiying the array structure or the original array.
The result should look like this

```
[
{data: [{text: "A",value: 100}, {text: "B", value: 74}], group: "Elephant"}, 
{data: [{text: "C", value: 63}, {text: "D", value: 1}], group: "Elephant"}, 
{data: [{text: "G", value: 72}, {text: "H", value: 74}], group: "Lion"}, 
{data: [{text: "M", value: 68}, {text: "N", value: 21}], group: "Lion"},
{data: [{text: "E",value: 37}, {text: "F", value: 54}], group: "Penguin"}, 
{data: [{text: "K", value: 76}, {text: "L", value: 38}], group: "Zebra"}, 
]
```

Comment: *"then sort based on the column index for each group"* You mean by `value`? And you've passed `ASC` as the sort order, but the values are sorted in *descending* order within their groups (apparently: `value: 100` comes before `value: 63` within `Elephant`). I'm not understanding the rules here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorr, that was my bad. I put that together manually which introduced the error.

Comment: Fundamentally it's just a two-key sort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields where the keys are `group` and `data[columnIndex].value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving this is immediate by using a `TrueSet` and an appropriate `representation` function.

To arrange your items first by `group` and then by `data[index].value`, simply represent each item (each row) using such a couple of properties:
`[item.group, item.data[index].value]` within a `TrueSet`. Nothing else is required.

```
const
    index = 1,
    repr = item => [item.group, item.data[index].value],

    got = TrueSet.of(repr, ORDER.ASCENDING, ORDER.DESCENDING)
        .letAll(data);
```

Please note that in your `_sortFunction()` you are mistakenly referring to `ASC` for what is actually a descending order. Therefore, I utilize the `ORDER.DESCENDING` comparator for values. However, the groups are sorted using the `ORDER.ASCENDING` comparator.

You can check the validity of the proposed solution by:

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import { ORDER } from "@ut8pia/classifier/global.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
        data = [
            {data: [{text: "A",value: 100}, {text: "B",value: 74}], group: "Elephant"},
            {data: [{text: "C",value: 63}, {text: "D",value: 1}], group: "Elephant"},
            {data: [{text: "E",value: 37}, {text: "F",value: 54}], group: "Penguin"},
            {data: [{text: "G", value: 72}, {text: "H", value: 74}], group: "Lion"},
            {data: [{text: "K", value: 76}, {text: "L", value: 38}], group: "Zebra"},
            {data: [{text: "M", value: 68}, {text: "N", value: 21}], group: "Lion"},
        ],

        expected = [            
            {data: [{text: "A",value: 100}, {text: "B", value: 74}], group: "Elephant"}, 
            {data: [{text: "C", value: 63}, {text: "D", value: 1}], group: "Elephant"}, 
            {data: [{text: "G", value: 72}, {text: "H", value: 74}], group: "Lion"}, 
            {data: [{text: "M", value: 68}, {text: "N", value: 21}], group: "Lion"},
            {data: [{text: "E",value: 37}, {text: "F", value: 54}], group: "Penguin"}, 
            {data: [{text: "K", value: 76}, {text: "L", value: 38}], group: "Zebra"}, 
        ];

assert.deepEqual(got.toArray(), expected)
```

It's important to highlight that the `TrueSet` is a sorted collection - a `queue`, of simple items. The method `toArray()` returns your original items, irrespective of their `representation` in the `TrueSet` internal tree structure. Nonetheless, such structure - a `Classifier`, allows grouping and querying your original items based on their representation.

To become acquainted with the concepts of `TrueSet`, `Classifier`, and the `representation` function, you might want to explore the [ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to modify the sortRowsByColumn function to first group the rows by their group property and then sort each group based on the specified column index. Its 2 steps I can print out:

```
const sortRowsByColumn = (rows, sortProps) => {
    if (!sortProps || !rows) {
        return rows;
    }

    const { indexOfColumnToSort, sortOrder } = sortProps;

    // Group rows by the 'group' key
    const grouped = rows.reduce((acc, row) => {
        acc[row.group] = acc[row.group] || [];
        acc[row.group].push(row);
        return acc;
    }, {});

    // Sort each group individually based on the specified column index
    Object.keys(grouped).forEach(group => {
        grouped[group].sort((a, b) => _sortFunction(a, b, indexOfColumnToSort, sortOrder));
    });

    // Combine the sorted groups back into a single array
    const sortedRows = Object.keys(grouped)
        .sort() // sort the groups alphabetically by their keys
        .reduce((acc, group) => acc.concat(grouped[group]), []);

    return sortedRows;
};
```

The function groups the rows by their group property using the reduce function.
Then, it sorts each group based on the specified column index using the _sortFunction.
After sorting each group, it combines these sorted groups back into a single array.
The groups themselves are sorted alphabetically by their keys (group names).