# Javascript, sort array of objects based on previous property values

Tags: javascript, sorting

Say I have an array of objects, each object has two properties, `LocID` and `d`.

For ease of illustration, let's say it's already sorted ascending by `d` .

```
var a = [
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
]
```

I want to a) keep it sorted by `d` (I know how to do that already), but I also want to sort based on `LocID` such that where `d` values are identical, it sorts by the previous value of `LocID`. This is difficult to explain, but to use my example...

a[0]'s `LocID` is 16660 --> a[1] and a[2] are the next two records with the nearest `d` value, and they're identical (22.9). I want a[1] and a[2] to be swapped in this case, so the 0 and 22.9 `d` valued `LocID` 16660 records are next to each other: this would involve swapping a[1] and a[2] in this case.

The only qualifier/caveat to this problem is that it is entirely possible that `LocID` values will reoccur along the way --> I want the `d` sort to be maintained to keep them "separated".

The desired result in my example would be:

```
[
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
]
```

I'm not sure I'm thinking about this right --> it is kinda a "pairing" algorithm more than anything. Anyways, any help/thoughts appreciated.

EDIT -->  fiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/wg8f3zun/

EDIT 2 --> stack snippet:

```js
var a = [
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
]
//yeah nah this doesn't work
//r = a.sort((a,b)=>a.d-b.d||a.LocID==b.LocID)

//ROUGH ALGO THAT MAY BE A SOLUTION
//result
var r = [] 
//"already picked indices" for tracking ones to skip
var pi = [] 
for (var i = 0; i< a.length; i++){
    //if already "picked" skip
    if (pi.includes(i)){continue}
  //add current object
    r.push(a[i]) 
    //look at next objects until LocIDs match
    //then push that result next, and add that index to the "skip list"
    for (var j = i+1; j<a.length;j++){
        if (a[j].LocID == a[i].LocID){
            r.push(a[j])
            pi.push(j)
            break
            }
        }
}
console.log(r)

//desired result
/* [{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
] */
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your attempt as code on this site, not only on JSFiddle. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to use an interface very similar to JSFiddle, but here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort an array of objects by multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913512/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-by-multiple-fields)

Comment: It looks to me that the required way of chaining is open to some ambiguities: When there are more than two elements with the same `d` value then only the first `LocId` value is defined as it is supposed to be the same as the previous element's value. But the order of the remaining ones is not clearly defined. In fact we might have to "look" into the next "d" group to find a possible match of `LocId` values there.

Comment: No, I know how to sort by multiple fields. My issue/problem is how to implement the desired sort behavior, which is dependent on both fields but isn't cut and dry like "ascending by LocID, descending by d".

Answer (score 1):

eheh it was harder understand your goal than find the solution .....

tecnically speaking you are not sorting you are actually modifying the objects content  so have a coulple of solution:

```js
// solution  one: 
// double sort the array  and than merge the result:
var a = [
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
];

var a1 = Array.from(a).sort((a, b) => a.d-b.d );
var a2 = Array.from(a).sort((a, b) => a.LocID-b.LocID );
for(a=[],i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
  a.push({'LocID':a2[i].LocID,'d':a1[i].d});
}
console.dir(a);


//solution two: implement your favorite sorting algo and sort both element
//in my case i'll use a simple bubble sort:

//lets reset a:
a = [
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
];


//lets "sort"

for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < a.length - i - 1; j++) {
    if (a[j].LocID > a[j + 1].LocID) {
      const lesser1 = a[j + 1].LocID;
      a[j + 1].LocID = a[j].LocID;
      a[j].LocID = lesser1;
    }
    if (a[j].d > a[j + 1].d) {
      const lesser2 = a[j + 1].d;
      a[j + 1].d = a[j].d;
      a[j].d = lesser2;
    }
  }
}

console.dir(a);
```

lets make some update :

```js
/*
_arr: array to sort
conf: object containing what to sort and how to sort.
      es: {LocID:'asc',d:'asc'}  => sort "LocID" (if found) field ascending 
                                    sort "d" (if found) field ascending
          {LocID:'desc',d:'desc'}  => sort "LocID" (if found) field descending 
                                    sort "d" (if found) field descending
*/
function gmerritt123Sort(_arr,conf){
  //this is my favorite way for clone an array but you can use 
  //any other working method (cloning array in javascript is a pain)
  this._clone=(e)=>{return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e));}
  
  //minimal check for array
  if(!Boolean(_arr) || !Array.isArray(_arr)){
    console.dir("first parameter must by an array");
    return _arr;
  }
  //minimal check for conf required
  if(!Boolean(conf) || Object.keys(conf).length==0){
    console.dir("conf required");
    return _arr;
  }

  //clone the array for not ovverride the original one
  //if you prefer change the original array you can comment the line below
  //and replace the parameter _arr with arr
  var arr = this._clone(_arr);


  //start reading conf and preparing sorting
  Object.keys(conf).forEach(i=>{
    if(!(i in arr[0])){
      //avoid to sort non existing keys
      delete conf[i];
    }else if(conf[i]!="desc"){
      //ascending sort (our default choice)
      conf[i] = this._clone(arr).sort((a, b) => a[i]-b[i] ); 
    }else if(conf[i]=="desc"){
      //descending sort (require explicitly set to "desc")
      conf[i] = this._clone(arr).sort((a, b) => b[i]-a[i] ); 
    }
  });

  //prepare the result merging all sorting
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    Object.keys(conf).forEach((j)=>{arr[i][j]=conf[j][i][j];});
  }
  return arr;
}

//lets do some test:

// original request:
var a1=[
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
];
console.log(gmerritt123Sort(a1,{LocID:'asc',d:'asc'}));


// mocking real case (or i think so ^_^ )request:
var a1=[
{'LocID':16660,d:0,a:1,b:"random string",c:9},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9,a:2,b:"aldkjf",c:4},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9,a:3,b:"òkj",c:8},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83,a:4,b:"ftf",c:8},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83,a:5,b:"irtyry",c:5},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5,a:6,b:"jkhkjh",c:5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5,a:7,b:"khjh",c:2},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0,a:8,b:"^_^ smile",c:1}
];
console.log("\n\n\nsort LocID asc , d asc  rest unsorted:");
console.log("============================================");
console.log(gmerritt123Sort(a1,{LocID:'asc',d:'asc'}));

console.log("\n\n\nsort LocID asc , d asc, a desc  rest unsorted:");
console.log("============================================");
console.log(gmerritt123Sort(a1,{LocID:'asc',d:'asc',a:'desc'}));

// i've forgot to  manage string so i dont dare try ^_^
```

i hope this can help you , have a nice day

Comment: That double sort + merge is clever :-D. I think the behavior is what's desired (at least it answers this SO post so I'll mark it as the solution (thanks). For my real use case these objects have other properties that I need to retain. The double-sort+merge method removes them. Any thoughts on if there's a way to finagle keeping them?

Comment: i try to add a general purpose method that use "multi sort + merge" tecnique ...i'm pretty sure that around you will find a solution that fit better to your real use case but maybe this could help in some way

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
];

a = a.sort((a, b) => a.d-b.d );

for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(let j = i; j < a.length - 1; j++) {
        if(a[j].d === a[j + 1].d && a[j].LocID > a[j + 1].LocID) {
            const tmp = a[j + 1];
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            a[j] = tmp
        }
    }
}
```

First sort them by the `d` and then one-by-one sort by LocID.

Result:

```
[{
  "LocID": 16660,
  "d": 0
}, {
  "LocID": 16654,
  "d": 22.9
}, {
  "LocID": 16660,
  "d": 22.9
}, {
  "LocID": 16650,
  "d": 37.83
}, {
  "LocID": 16654,
  "d": 37.83
}, {
  "LocID": 16650,
  "d": 63.5
}, {
  "LocID": 16655,
  "d": 63.5
}, {
  "LocID": 16660,
  "d": 70
}]
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desire result.

Answer (score 0):

1. sort the array by `d`
2. get it index and sort by `d` again + look for previous and next `d` in the sorted array, sort by `LocID` accordingly
3. convert the index to the final sorted array
4. you can have any additional properties in items

```js
var arr = [
{'LocID':16660,d:0},
{'LocID':16654,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16660,d:22.9},
{'LocID':16650,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16654,d:37.83},
{'LocID':16650,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16655,d:63.5},
{'LocID':16660,d:70.0}
];

const index = arr.toSorted((a,b)=>a-b).map((_, i) => i).sort((i, j) => {
  const a = arr[i], b = arr[j];
  const out = a.d - b.d;
  if(out) return out;
  const prev = arr[Math.min(i,j)-1];
  const next = arr[Math.max(i,i)+1];
  if(prev.LocID <= next.LocID){
    return a.LocID < b.LocID ? -1 : 1;
  }else{
    return b.LocID < a.LocID ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return 0;
});

const result = index.map(i => arr[i]); 
result.forEach(r => console.log(JSON.stringify(r)));
```