# Jquery - Sort object

Tags: javascript

I know, I've found many examples to sort an Object. But that makes me a little bit confused (I am not so pro to check wich is the fastest and cleanest method for me).

I hope somebody can help.

**My Object looks like**

```
tt_results = {};
tt_results[6815631] = new Array('85', 'blibee', 'blaerb', 'bluo', 'tkone', 'tkeeee_seve', '382261471' );
tt_results[1563157] = new Array('25', 'blib', 'blab', 'bluerro', 'tkerone', 'tk_seve', '382266851' );
```

I want to sort the timestamp.

Thanks in advance!

Peter

Comment: Objects (`{}`) are not ordered; only arrays (`[]`) are ordered.

Comment: Hi Gumbo, that explain everything. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer to a similar question here: [Trying to sort a custom JavaScript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368036/trying-to-sort-a-custom-javascript-object/3368210#3368210)

Basically, you can't sort objects themselves - it doesn't make sense. But you can process the object in sorted order by sorting the keys and then iterating over the sorted keys.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned in the comment you cannot sort objects.

In terms of general js performance a good resource for x-browser tests & results check out [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/browse). There is an array sort test [here](http://jsperf.com/sort-array-of-objects)

Comment: Thank you for the nice test Page.

Comment: Check if the link is broken