# Pattern for loading a lot of script snippets on DOM ready-event, without IE 8 popping up a script time-out warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I'm working on an interface with a lot of JavaScript - all small, self-contained snippets of code, designed to do various things on the interface.

All of the snippets (or blocks of functionality, if you will) are placed inside the same scope; the DOM ready event. This is so that the various snippets are able to share a few scoped global variables.

Here's how it's structured...

```
$(function ()
{
    var SCOPED_GLOBAL_1;
    var SCOPED_GLOBAL_2;
    // Etc.


    // A snippet of code designed to enable X functionality

    // Another snippet of code designed to enable Y functionality

    // Etc.
});
```

Using this approach, I get the dreaded script time-out pop-up, because of the large amount of code being executed.

Internet Explorer 8 determines script time-out's [based on how many calls are made](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/01/05/what-determines-that-a-script-is-long-running/)... And a lot of calls are being made... A lot!

I've done some testing, and as far as I can tell, the only way to avoid the pop-up is to use setTimeout, and gradually execute chunks of the code.

I've tried splitting up the code into multiple calls to the DOM ready event, but it seems that Internet Explorer 8 interprets those calls as if they were one call. (Same signature when profiling).

The code is gonna get messy if I need to implement the setTimeout approach. And sharing scoped globals won't be easy.

Have you guys got a pattern to help me out?

**Update**

As some of you have suggested, optimizing the code would be a way to handle this. I am sure that there is room for optimizations in the code, but as I see it; it is simply the bulk of code that's the issue here and not how it performs.

There are a lot of pre- set-up code being run, which initializes various UI components. It is this code that is causing problems in Internet Explorer 8... *by the sheer number of calls being made.* Not how long it takes for the code to execute.

The code runs fast and fine in all other browsers, taking on average a second and a half to load (which is fast, compared to how much stuff is going on). The problem here is that Internet Explorer 8 defines a script as being slow, by the number of calls being done, whilst all other browsers (and IE 9, seemingly) defines time-out's by the time it takes the code to execute.

Comment: What is the question here? What kind of answer do you expect? A universal refactoring pattern? I'm afraid there is none. The approach using `setTimeout` is probably the last thing to consider. Before that, refactore/optimize your code.

Comment: I'm not sure, but wrapping your code in an anonymous function shouldn't have much to do with whether the script time-out is triggered. It's more likely your code is not very optimal. Consider profiling (timing) your code and try to optimize the slow parts.

Comment: Ok, ignoring optimization for now (although it's still probably a good thing to do), have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/how-can-i-give-control-back-briefly-to-the-browser-during-intensive-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Short of refactoring, `setTimeout` is probably the simplest trick in the book. It doesn't have to be messy either:

```
$(function () {
    var SCOPED_GLOBAL_1, SCOPED_GLOBAL_2;

    // Add code in blocks
    var codeBlocks = [];
    codeBlocks.push(function () {
        // A snippet of code
    });
    codeBlocks.push(function () {
        // Another snippet of code
    });

    // Execute code in blocks
    while (codeBlocks.length) {
        (function (func) {
            setTimeout(func, 0);
        })(codeBlocks.shift());
    }
});
```

This essentially creates a queue of any number of blocks of code to execute, and executes them individually, in order, with `setTimeout()`.