# Is it possible to asynchron repaint a website (not blocking the UI)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, repaint

Lets say I make an Ajax call. The handler for the response could be this:

```
function handleAjaxResponse(data) {
    //Do changes to the dom, wich takes 2 seconds
}
```

Until the Response is in coming, everything is fine. The problem is in handling it.

My problem is with the latest Versions of *Internet Explorer* and *Firefox*. This browsers, block the UI Process until `handleAjaxResponse` is full executed. With block I mean, I can do nothing, the website is hanging.

I found out, that *Google Chrome* has no problem with this.

So is there a way, to repaint the document, without blocking the UI Process in FF and IE?

Comment: So your ajax is asynchronous and working properly, but your DOM manipulations are too heavy?

Comment: You could break up your DOM repaints into smaller chunks and wrap each one in a `setTimeout(function(){}, 0);`  This will push the function to the bottom of the stack and let the browser's UI thread run more frequently and hopefully make it lock up less.

Comment: For example I use the plugin `bootstrap-select`, wich is a searchable `select` with 200 items for example. Simple painting this can take 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break up the changes to smaller functions and call them as `setTimeout` callbacks. That way the UI has a chance to handle user input and not hang.

See also:

[How can I give control back (briefly) to the browser during intensive JavaScript processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/how-can-i-give-control-back-briefly-to-the-browser-during-intensive-javascript)

Comment: This is good point :) Will accept it as soon as I can. Thank you! :)