# How to prevent error messages at the browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm writing a web application which conducts calculations that stress the browser and the computer's CPU.

**The program should act as follows, and the stressing is not something that is the problem, or needs to be solved.**

I would like to prevent the browser (Chrome and Firefox especially) from popping up an error message such as *'page is unresponsive'*.

How can I do it using javaScript?

I prefer not to change browser setting (I don't want that users of the app have to change Chrome settings manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should break up the task into pieces if possible (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210821/how-can-i-give-control-back-briefly-to-the-browser-during-intensive-javascript)) and delegate out the work to [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers).

Using Web Workers is pretty simple, you just specify the URI of the script you want to run (`main.js`):

```
var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
```

To communicate with the worker, you pass messages back and forth. To send a message to the worker, call `myWorker.postMessage` (`main.js`):

```
myWorker.postMessage('some value');
```

To receive messages on the worker, define an `onmessage` handler like this. You can also `postMessage` back to the main thread (`worker.js`):

```
onmessage = function(e) {
  // e.data === 'some value'
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  postMessage('worker result');
}
```

Back in your main thread, you can listen for messages from your worker like this (`main.js`):

```
myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
  // e.data === 'worker result'
  console.log('Message received from worker');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this developer tools in Chrome

```
chrome://chrome-urls/
```

Go to For Debug

Might help in case of Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Webworkers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Those run in threads in the background and are designed for heavy load tasks.